# differentiate between button clicks using pending intent

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am showing a custom notification (FCM). custom notification has two buttons `approve` and `deny`.

I have managed to create pending intent and a broadcast receiver and now I know in `onReceive` when the button is clicked.

How can i differentiate between button clicks in onReceive, I tried to pass extras on the intent, but `intent.getStringExtra("clicked")` gave me null value.

what is the right way of knowing which button is clicked `approve` , `deny`

This is the code I tried.
Thanks for your help in advance
R

```
      override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("FCMService", "onMessageReceived START ${isAppOnForeground()}")
        if(!isAppOnForeground()) {
            val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_small
            )
            val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_large
            )

            val title = message.data[MSG_TITLE]
            val subTitle = message.data[MSG_SUB_TITLE]

            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

// Apply the layouts to the notification
            val customNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this,
                CarInfoProcessingService.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
            )
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build()

            val switchIntent = Intent(this, SwitchButtonListener::class.java)
            switchIntent.putExtra("clicked", "btnApprove")
            val pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0,
                switchIntent, 0
            )
     //TWO BUTTONS WITH SAME PENDING SWITCH INTENT
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnApprove, pendingSwitchIntent)
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDeny, pendingSwitchIntent)

            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(0, customNotification)
        }
        Log.d("FCMService", "onMessageReceived END")
    }

    class SwitchButtonListener : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d("fcmService", "onReceive ${intent.getStringExtra("clicked")}")
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".messaging.FcmService$SwitchButtonListener"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Button_Clicked"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

EDIT : Updated code that might help others

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("FCMService", "onMessageReceived START ${isAppOnForeground()}")
        if(!isAppOnForeground()) {
            val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_small
            )
            val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(
                packageName,
                R.layout.plugin_requires_approval_notification_large
            )

            val title = message.data[MSG_TITLE]
            val subTitle = message.data[MSG_SUB_TITLE]

            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title)
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubTitle, subTitle)

// Apply the layouts to the notification
            val customNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this,
                CarInfoProcessingService.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
            )
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build()

            val approveIntent = Intent(this, CustomNotificationListener::class.java)
            approveIntent.putExtra("onClickListener", "approve")
            val pendingApproveIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                0,
                approveIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnApprove, pendingApproveIntent)

            val denyIntent = Intent(this, CustomNotificationListener::class.java)
            denyIntent.putExtra("onClickListener", "deny")
            val pendingDenyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                1,
                denyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )

            notificationLayoutExpanded.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDeny, pendingDenyIntent)

            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(0, customNotification)
        }
        Log.d("FCMService", "onMessageReceived END")
    }

    class CustomNotificationListener : BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Inject
        lateinit var chargeSessionRepo: ChargeSessionRepository

        private var lastChargeStatus: ChargeStatusDTO? = null

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d("fcmService", "onReceive ${intent.getStringExtra("onClickListener")}")
            when(intent.getStringExtra("onClickListener")) {
                "approve" -> {
                    
                }
                "deny" -> {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "How can i differentiate between button clicks in onReceive" -- use two separate `PendingIntent` objects with different IDs (the second parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and different underlying `Intent` objects (e.g., different extras).

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare thank you for responding, so should I be creating a new class which extends BroadcastReceiver which will be new listener?

Comment: The two `Intent` objects can point to the same class if you want. That class would examine the extras to see which broadcast it received.

Comment: when I try to get the extras, `${intent.getStringExtra("clicked")}`, I receive a null object

Comment: Presumably you created the `PendingIntent` in a previous run of the app without the extra. You are passing `0` for the last parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. That means "do not create a `PendingIntent` if one already exists in the system for this ID". Instead, pass `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: thank you so much @CommonsWare that works thanks a TON, you are always very helpful and very knowledgable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two distinct, up-to-date `PendingIntent` objects, wrapped around different `Intent` objects (e.g., ones with differing extras).

For "distinct", you need the IDs of the `PendingIntent` objects to be different. The ID is the second parameter to the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call.

For "up-to-date", you need to update any existing `PendingIntent` that your code might have created previously. For that, pass `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as the fourth parameter to the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call.